# Rank-constrained linear combination of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have several real symmetric matrices, say, $A_1, A_2,\dots, A_n$. I want to know if there exists a complex linear combination of these matrices

$$M := \sum_{i=1}^n c_i A_i , \quad c_i \in \mathbb{C}$$

satisfying $\text{rank}(M)\leq2$. If there are such $c_i$'s, what are they? Is there any method of doing this?

Comment: See [this Math Overflow discussion.][1]


  [1]: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/149595/a-question-on-eigenvalues

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1245111/339790)

Answer (score 0):

You want to find $(c_1, \ldots, c_n)$ such that the $3 \times 3$ minors of $M$ are all $0$.  Each of these minors is a polynomial in $c_1, \ldots, c_n$.
That may be rather a lot of minors, so I would start with maybe $n$ of them, find the solutions, and then see which make $M$ have rank $\le 2$.

Comment: That's exactly the method I adopt now. But when n is large, solving such number of cubic equations is not an easy job.