# Turkevicius inequality

Tags: inequality, polynomials, sum-of-squares-method, buffalo-way

From Zdravko Cvetkovski's [Inequalities — Theorems, Techniques and Selected](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-23792-8):

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ be positive real numbers. Prove that:
> $$a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4+2abcd \geq a^2b^2+ a^2c^2+ a^2d^2+ b^2c^2+ b^2d^2+ c^2d^2.$$

---

Please suggest how to prove this inequality using basic methods. No logarithms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume $a\geq b\geq c\geq d.$ Let
$$f(a) = a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4+2abcd - a^2b^2-a^2c^2-a^2d^2-b^2c^2-b^2d^2-c^2d^2.$$ Then, $$f'(a) = 4a^3 -2a(b^2+c^2+d^2)+2bcd$$
and
$$f''(a) = 12a^2 - 2b^2-2c^2-2d^2\geq 0.$$ Hence, $f'$ is increasing and $f'(b) = 2(b^3-b(c^2+d^2)+bcd) \geq 2b(b-c)(b-d)\geq 0.$ Thus, $f(a)$ is increasing and therefore:

$$f(a)\geq f(b) = b^4+c^4+d^4+2b^2cd-2b^2c^2-2b^2d^2-c^2d^2 = $$$$b^4-2b^2(c^2+d^2-cd)+c^4+d^4-c^2d^2 = (b^2 - c^2-d^2+cd)^2+2cd(c-d)^2\geq 0.$$

Comment: Please add some spaces dude, it becomes tough to read

Comment: Regarding $$f'(b) = 2(b^3-b(c^2+d^2)+bcd) = 2b(b-c)(b-d)\geq 0.$$ I think  $f'(b) = 4(b^3-b(c^2+d^2)+bcd)$. And $ 2(b^3-b(c^2+d^2)+bcd) \not= 2b(b-c)(b-d)$. Please check.

Comment: @ carat. Right, I meant to say $b^2-c^2-d^2+cd\geq b^2-bc-bd+cd = (b-c)(b-d)\geq 0.$ Just fixed it now.

Comment: I'm clear now. Thank you, dezdichado.

Comment: @carat no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a\geq b\geq c\geq d$.

Thus, $$d(d-a)(d-b)(d+2c)+d(d-a)(d+2b)(d-c)+d(d+2a)(d-b)(d-c)\geq0$$ or
$$d^4-(ab+ac+bc)d^2+2abcd\geq0.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$a^4+b^4+c^4\geq(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)d^2+a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2-b^2)^2\geq\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2d^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2((a+b)^2-d^2)\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Here $\sum\limits_{cyc}$ means $\sum\limits_{a\rightarrow b\rightarrow c\rightarrow a}$.

Also, we can use the BW.

Let $a=\min\{a,b,c,d\}$, $b=a+u$, $c=a+v$ and $d=a+w$.

Thus, $u$, $b$ and $w$ are non-negatives and
$$\sum_{cyc}a^4+2abcd-\frac{1}{6}\sum_{sym}a^2b^2=$$
$$\sum_{cyc}(3u^2-2uv)a^2+\sum_{cyc}\left(4u^3-u^2v-u^2w+\frac{2}{3}uvw\right)a+\sum_{cyc}(u^4-u^2v^2)\geq0.$$

Also there are proofs by EV Method and by SOS.

Comment: Thank you. I have 2 questions. What is the motivation for this?  $$d(d-a)(d-b)(d+2c)+d(d-a)(d+2b)(d-c)+d(d+2a)(d-b)(d-c)\geq0$$ And how does this come ? $$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2((a+b)^2-d^2)\geq0$$

Comment: @carat I want to get $2abcd$ and I want to get as much as possible given terms. For the second question. $(a^2-b^2)^2-(a-b)^2d^2=(a-b)^2(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2d^2=(a-b)^2((a+b)^2-d^2).$

Comment: Regarding my second question, since it is cyclic sum, how do you prove that it is greater or equal to zero ?

Comment: @carat Because $d=\min\{a,b,c,d\}$.

Comment: I meant,
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2((a+b)^2-d^2)= (a-b)^2((a+b)^2-d^2)+ (b-c)^2((b+c)^2-a^2)+ (c-d)^2((c+d)^2-b^2)+ (d-a)^2((d+a)^2-c^2)$$,
the second and third terms of RHS can be negative.

Comment: @carat No! It's cyclic $a\rightarrow b\rightarrow c\rightarrow a$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Michael Rozenberg.

Comment: @carat You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

To ensure non-negativity, let

$$a =: x_1^2, \qquad b =: x_2^2, \qquad c =: x_3^2, \qquad d =: x_4^2$$

Hence, proving the given inequality is reduced to proving than an octic form is globally non-negative over $\Bbb R^4$. Using [Macaulay2](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2) (version 1.16) with package [SumsOfSquares](https://sums-of-squares.github.io/sos):

```
i1 : needsPackage( "SumsOfSquares" );

i2 : R = QQ[x1,x2,x3,x4];

i3 : f = x1^8 + x2^8 + x3^8 + x4^8 + 2*x1^2*x2^2*x3^2*x4^2 - x1^4*x2^4 - x1^4*x3^4 - x1^4*x4^4 - x2^4*x3^4 - x2^4*x4^4 - x3^4*x4^4;

i4 : sosPoly solveSOS f;
```

Unfortunately, the SOS decomposition produced by Macaulay2 is simply **too large** to include in this answer, as it exceeds $30000$ characters. I would not call this a basic method. Nonetheless, I find this exercise in mathematical brutality interesting.

---

[polynomials](/questions/tagged/polynomials) [sum-of-squares-method](/questions/tagged/sum-of-squares-method) [macaulay2](/questions/tagged/macaulay2)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120681/discussion-on-answer-by-rodrigo-de-azevedo-turkevicius-inequality).