# Practical applications of semidefinite programming

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convex-optimization, applications, semidefinite-programming

I am looking for practical applications of semidefinite- programming. So far, I found that the low-rank matrix completion problem (recomendendattion matrices) can be expressed as a semidefinite program. The same goes for the combinatorial problem MAX-CUT.

1. What is a practical applications of the MAX-CUT problem?
2. What would be a third practical applications of semidefinite programming?

Would be nice if anyone could recommend any references. Thanks.

Comment: [Do they use semidefinite programming in industry?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/15926/20417)

Comment: One application is determining whether a polynomial can be expressed as a sum of squares. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2414847).

Comment: If you haven't already read Boyd and Vandenberghe, it discusses a bunch of applications of SDPs (including in the exercises and the additional exercises).

Comment: I've looked into  Boyd and Vandenberghe. Problem is, these problems are  convex or quasiconvex and since semidef. problems are just a subfield, things dont really fit. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: @Rodrigo the sum of squares is quite interesting. I read https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410994/write-x2-y2-z22-3-x3-y-y3-z-z3-x-as-a-sum-of-three-squ/2414847#2414847 .                                  
How would I have to choose A_i if I want to transform min tr(Q) s.t. A(Q)=b,Q⪰O to the standard sdp form    min tr(C,Q) s.t. Q⪰O ,tr(A_i,Q)=b_i   .

Comment: @P.Müller It's already in standard form! Look at the code.

Comment: you are right :) thanks. Sadly your matrix Q is only positiv semidefinite so I cant do the cholesky decomposition. How do you get the matrix 6x2 square root =  
                 Matrix([[   1,          0],
                           [-1/2,  sqrt(3)/2],
                           [-1/2, -sqrt(3)/2],
                           [-3/2, -sqrt(3)/2],
                           [   0,    sqrt(3)],
                           [ 3/2, -sqrt(3)/2]])?