# For $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R} $, prove that $ x(x+y)^5+y(y+z)^5+z(z+x)^5 \geq \frac{32}{243}(x+y+z)^6 $

Tags: inequality

> For real numbers $x,y,z$ ,prove that $$x(x+y)^5+y(y+z)^5+z(z+x)^5 \geq \frac{32}{243}(x+y+z)^6$$

For $x,y,z>0$ I have a simple solution:

By Hölder inequality:
$$\sum x(x+y)^5  \geq \frac{(\sum x(x+y))^5}{(\sum x)^4}\ge \frac{(\frac{2}{3}(\sum x)^2)^5}{(\sum x)^4}=\frac{32}{243}(x+y+z)^6 $$

But for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ the solution failed.

How can I prove the inequality for  $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @CalvinLin Do you mean $(\sum_{cyc} x(x+y)^5)(x + y + z)^4 \ge (\sum_{cyc} x(x+y))^5 $ does not hold for $x = -3, y = 1, z = 1$ or even $x = -2, y = 1,  z= 1$?

Comment: @RiverLi Can you write the SOS expression of this inequality?

Comment: My SOS expression is too complicated. Hope someone can give simple SOS.

Comment: @RiverLi It's nice as well if you express it to Matrix form. By the way, You can upload the code if your SOS expression is too long.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit (2024-02-22)**. An SOS (Sum of Squares) solution simpler than my old one

*Remarks*: The proof is motivated by computer. It is still complicated to verify that $Q$ is positive semidefinite by hand. Hope to see a proof which can be verified by hand (the proof itself can be motivated by computer).

Let $a := x + y, b := y + z, c := z + x$.
We have the following SOS expression
$$x(x + y)^5 + y(y + z)^5 + z(z + x)^5 -  \frac{32}{243}(x + y + z)^6
= \frac{1}{972}Z^\mathsf{T} Q Z$$
where
$$Z := [{a}^{3},{a}^{2}b,a{b}^{2},{b}^{3},{a}^{2}c,abc,{b}^{2}c,a{c}^{2},b{c}
^{2},{c}^{3}],
$$
and
$$Q := \begin{pmatrix}
 A & B \\
 B^\top & C 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with
$$A := \left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} 484&-249&-217&-89&237
\\-249&404&69&-165&-38\\-217&69&
300&237&-150\\ -89&-165&237&484&-20
\\ 237&-38&-150&-20&300\end {array} \right],
$$
and
$$B :=  \left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} 8&100&-165&-20&-89\\ -
10&-40&-40&-31&100\\ 0&-38&-31&-150&-20
\\ 8&-249&100&-217&-89\\ 0&-31&69&
-150&-217\end {array} \right] ,$$
and
$$C :=  \left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} 6&-10&-10&0&8\\ -10&
404&-40&69&-165\\ -10&-40&404&-38&-249
\\ 0&69&-38&300&237\\ 8&-165&-249&
237&484\end {array} \right] .$$

Comment: What’s the theory behind this? (Also there are some cubic terms?)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch For basic idea of SOS, you may see Rodrigo de Azevedo's excellent answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410994/write-x2-y2-z22-3-x3-y-y3-z-z3-x-as-a-sum-of-three-squ/2414847#2414847

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(a,b,c)=a(a+b)^5+b(b+c)^5+c(c+a)^5- \frac{32}{243}(a+b+c)^6$$and the SOS tool gives the following result
$$\begin{aligned} f(a,b,c)  & = \frac{10}{818181}\sum \left(- 156 a^{3} - 544 a^{2} b + 143 a^{2} c - 403 a b^{2} + 395 a c^{2} + 149 b^{2} c + 260 b c^{2} + 156 c^{3}\right)^{2} \\  & + \frac{1}{4332331332}\left(\sum a \left(34418 a^{2} + 39597 a b - 14871 b^{2} - 59144 b c\right)\right)^{2} \\  & + \frac{1}{45175369079215116}\left(\sum a b \left(31282489 a - 450959 b - 30831530 c\right)\right)^{2} + \frac{48435918625}{218758445577}\left(\sum a b \left(b - c\right)\right)^{2} \end{aligned}$$
By the way, the original problem is true by Buffalo Way. See [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=243%5C%2840%29xPower%5B%5C%2840%29x%2By%5C%2841%29%2C5%5D%2ByPower%5B%5C%2840%29y%2Bz%5C%2841%29%2C5%5D%2BzPower%5B%5C%2840%29z%2Bx%5C%2841%29%2C5%5D%5C%2841%29-32Power%5B%5C%2840%29x%2By%2Bz%5C%2841%29%2C6%5D%5C%2844%29x%3Da%5C%2844%29y%3Da%2Bu%5C%2844%29z%3Da%2Bv)

Comment: Very nice SOS.  For Buffalo Way, do you consider the **real** numbers $x, y, z$?

Comment: By the way, did you try the SOS tool for your another question: $(a+b+c-3)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-3\right)+abc+\frac{1}{abc}\ge 2$?

Comment: @RiverLi Yes, I see BW is not easy in this case. Btw, my tool works only for homogenous inequality.

Comment: Your matrix proof is very interesting! I upvoted it.

Comment: Your expression is in a better form which is clearly non-negative, while my expression isn't.

Comment: @Helloworld Just wanna know, does your tool share the same principle with [Triple-SOS](https://github.com/ForeverHaibara/Triple-SOS) tool (developed by ForeverHaibara)? I mean, the results they look almost identical.